# wi-fi drivers for laptop xiaomi air 13

Tags: drivers, wireless

Has anybody had experience with installing ubuntu on xiaomi air 13?
wi-fi does not work after installation and google has exactly zero results regarding this
thank you

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Try blacklisting the "acer-wmi" and "acer-wireless" modules.

Comment: What does not work? Wi-fi or whole Ubuntu?

Comment: Edit your question and  add more details like..what problem u exactly have!.. question title says wifi not working... description says ubuntu not working

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: patrick yi you are the man!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem too, I saw you already fixed the problem, but for the next Xiaomi Ubuntu user:

Use `rfkill list` to see the list of available wireless devices, the result will be something like:

```
   rfkill list
        0: phy0: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
        1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: yes
            Hard blocked: no
        2: hci0: Bluetooth
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
```

then you will see that an acer wireless lan is also there and this loaded module is interrupting the correct one so you can deactivate it, the next steps show how to do it.

With this command you can see which Kernel modules are loaded
`lsmod | egrep '_acpi|_bluetooth|intel_oaktrail|_laptop|_rfkill|_wmi'`

my result was:

```
acer_wmi               20480  0
dell_wmi_aio           16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 dell_wmi_aio,acer_wmi
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_acpi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  4 dell_wmi_aio,acer_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  3 i915_bpo,acer_wmi,nouveau
```

so the problem was the module called acer_wmi so I deactivate it `sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi`

then the problem was solved temporally but after a restart the module will be loaded again so as suggested in the comments the solution is to put it in a black list

Add to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` the following line `blacklist acer-wmi` and done.

Comment: on my mi 13.3 `sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi` block the touchpad and keyboard however adding it to the blacklist solved any problem at the next reboot

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works great, thank you!