# No wi-fi network after install

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.10

i just installed ubuntu 16:10 on my Xiaomi Air 13 "uncommon device i know" but i'm not able to see any wifi connection.
This problem occurred right after the install, since before "during the try ubuntu and all the installation" i was able to see and connect w/out any problem.

If i go to All Settings -> Network i'm not able to turn on the wifi "it switch back to off as soon as i turn it on".

Nothing also in Software and update -> more driver.

What should i do ? :C

Edit:I was able to fix it by this metod here 
[wi-fi drivers for laptop xiaomi air 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829863/wi-fi-drivers-for-laptop-xiaomi-air-13)

But now i can't find any programm/app on Ubuntu Software C. "like geany".
Is this problem somehow related to the fix that i just found ?

Comment: Run this command: "sudo lshw -c network", and edit your answer with its results.

Comment: I was able to fix it by this metod here 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/829863/wi-fi-drivers-for-laptop-xiaomi-air-13

But now i can't find any programm/app on Ubuntu Software C. "like geany".
Is this problem somehow related to the fix that i just found ?

Comment: Haha that was actually my answer (in the comments), but regarding the software center that fix shouldn't have affected anything.Could you tell me exactly what happens when you try to search for a program in the Software Center?